# Algorithm to pack N rectangles into a larger one

Tags: algorithm, packing

I am writing a (JavaScript) thumbnail generator and this bit of the project involves placing the N thumbnails in regular rows and columns within a larger target space, including a border around the outside and "visually pleasing" borders between each thumbnail.

Each thumbnail is large and already scaled to turn it into a thumbnail so one approach is to change the  size of each thumbnail to help fulfil the packing conditions.

Each thumbnail is of an identical size. The number of thumbnails could be anywhere from a small number (4??) to something around 100.

I have been looking for some ideas and there seem to be plenty of example code for algorithms that pack as many rectangles of different sizes into the densest possible configuration - but I haven't come across anything similar to what I am trying to do.

If anyone can point me at some code or even an algorithm, I'd be very grateful.